# Unit test fails when stream/event has pipe(takeUntil(destroy))

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs

Angular: 9.1.13; RxJS: 6.6.3; Karma: 4.3.0; jasmine-core: 2.6.2

We have a component that has service which does something with streams and events.

Each such component method unsubscribes from stream/event when it is destroyed by means of calling `this._destroy.next()`, subject declared as `private _destroy = new Subject()` in `ngOnDestroy` hook.

Everything seems to be good until we run unit test. Method and test example can be found below.

It is unclear why test fails when subscribed to a service stream/event with `takeUntil`.

(another use case) not working with stubs returning observables that have `pipe(takeUntil(destroy))`

Error when running test using jasmine/karma and phantom.js

```js
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.service.getServicePackages().pipe(Object(rxjs_operators__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__["takeUntil"])(this._destroy))')
```

Method example:

```js
getServicePackages(): void {
 this.service.getServicePackages().pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy)).subscribe(() => ... );
}
```

Test example:

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  serviceStub = {
    getServicePackages: () => ({ subscribe: () => ({}) }),
    // v2 -> getServicePackages: () => ({ subscribe: (): Observable<TYPE> => of({}) }),
  }
})

it('...', () => {
  const serviceStub = TestBed.inject(PackageService);

  spyOn(serviceStub, 'getServicePackage').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(component, 'getServicePackage').and.callThrough();

  component.getServicePackage();

  expect(component.getServicePackage).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(serviceStub.getServicePackage).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: could you provide code how you declare serviceStub?

Comment: @Andrei, please see updated Test Example

Answer (score 0):

the problem becomes obvious if we put 2 lines togeter

```
serviceStub = {
    getServicePackages: () => ({ subscribe: () => ({}) }),
    // v2 -> getServicePackages: () => ({ subscribe: (): Observable<TYPE> => of({}) }),
};
// and then in code of component
serviceStub.getServicePackages().pipe(does not matter what); // here it doesn't have pipe method
```

i would suggest returning the observable itself. And in case you want to test also events - return a subject.

```
servicePackagesSubject = new Subject();
serviceStub = {
    getServicePackages: jasmine.createSpy('getServicePackages').and.returnValue(servicePackagesSubject),
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to move forward on cases like this:

```
// As mentioned earlier by @Andrei, it does not matter about the pipe operators. 

// In your test case, create a mock service, return a value, and use it as a useClass method in the providers and simply spyOn your component method. Something like this: 


// In your spec file, 

@Injectable() 
class MockService extends YourOriginalService {
  getServicePackages() {
    // Since you are subscribing, i am assuming this returns an observable, hence
    // the 'of' operator
    
    const mockData = {fill your mockData here};
    return of(mockData);
  }
}

// In your before each, add the mockService to your providers 

let mockService: YourOriginalService;
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [],
      ....
      providers: [
        {
          provide: YourOriginalService,
          useClass: MockService
        }
      ]
      ......
    }).compileComponents();

    mockService = TestBed.get(YourOriginalService);
  }));



/// Now your test case turns to this: 

it('should call the #getServicePackages() method in component', () => {
  
  spyOn(component, 'getServicePackages').and.callThrough();
  component.getServicePackages();
  expect(component.getServicePackages).toHaveBeenCalled();

});


// Now if you want to test the 'error' part in the subscribe, you can take care of that in this test case like this: 

it('should call the #getServicePackages() method in component, for error scenario', () => {
  // Assuming its an API Call, otherwise replace the status object with your mock error object
  spyOn(component, 'getServicePackages').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(mockService, 'getServicePackages')
    .and.returnValue(throwError(of({status: 500})));
  component.getServicePackages();
  expect(component.getServicePackages).toHaveBeenCalled();

});

// Note: Please don't mix the service success scenario coverage and service error scenario coverage in the same test case. Use 2 test cases like above.
```